Can "one" be used instead of uncountable nouns?
In this thread, I'd like to find out whether "one" can be used instead of an uncountable noun (e.g. "butter").
All examples below are mine.

(1a) A: I like butter. B: I like it too. — I think this is correct.
(1b) A: I like butter. B: I like one too. — I don't know whether this is correct.
Is (1b) correct?

(2a) A: I like the butter which is sold in the neighboring market. B: I like it too. — I think this is correct.
(2b) A: I like the butter which is sold in the neighboring market. B: I like one too. — I don't know whether this is correct.
Is (2b) correct?

I don't know whether terminology is necessary here, and don't want to complicate the thread too much, but if, for some reason, need be, then according to the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language" (CGEL), I'm inferring the following:
"One" as an anaphor can be only determinative or pro-nominal.
CGEL says the pro-nominal "one" can't refer to an uncountable nominal.
CGEL does not say whether the determinative "one" can refer to an uncountable NP or not.
That's why I had to come with some sentences where the determinative "one" refers to uncountable NPs: "butter" in (1b) and "the butter which is sold in the neighboring market" in (2b).
In more detail, "one" in (1b) and (2b) is a determinative which is functioning as a fused determiner-head.
Also, anticipating conversations about possible duplicates, I'm convinced to note that there is another similar thread on this forum but it doesn't help to answer my questions because in that thread, "one" is pro-nominal, and in mine, "one" is determinative.

All this terminology is entirely besides the point. No, you can't use "one" to refer to an uncountable noun.

I agree with @DanielRoseman.  You can't use "one" here because you can't say "a butter".

You can't use one butter either. Unless there's implied context: I'll have one butter [cookie] and one chocolate [cookie]

This question is similar to: Can we use 'one' after uncountable nouns?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In your examples, it is a pronoun, and its referent is clear to the addressee since it refers back to the object most recently mentioned. By contrast, pretty much the only way one is used pronominally is as a reference to a person, as in One’s first idea isn’t always the best, Your 2b is not correct.
What you could say in the context of your 2b is things like I like that one too. As it happens, in that sort of construction, one is a noun; it’s roughly equivalent to choice or alternative.

It's very strange to me that you wrote the following is correct: "A: I like the butter which is sold in the neighboring market. B: I like that one too." As far as I understand, according to CGEL, this is incorrect because "one" in "that one" is pro-nominal. And CGEL says on page 1515: the pro-nominal "one" is a count noun, and hence cannot take non-count nouns or nominals as antecedent.

"But "the butter which is sold in the neighboring market" is indeed a count noun. The market might carry any number of butters (salted, unsalted, butter from Irish cows living near the sea, butter from cows fed on clover, light butter, locally churned butter, whatever), and you happen to like the one they carry.   You like the particular variety of butter they carry.

Augmenting @TimR’s comment here, I’ll point out that I like the butter which is sold in the neighboring market would serve very nicely as an answer to the question Which butter do you buy, this one, that one, or some other? The noun phrase which butter can be understood as a shortening of which variety of butter or of which brand of butter. In any case, butter as used here is a count noun.

@TimR Am I right that: 1) "A: I want a cake. B: I want one too." is correct because "one" refers to the countable noun "cake"; 2) "A: I want cake. B: I want one too." is incorrect because "one" refers to the uncountable noun "cake" ? Thanks.

@Lovii  Pretty much, though I think it is debatable whether one is a reference in the same way that he or she is a reference. When speaker #1 says  "I want cake" they're referring to the category or type of dessert, and when they say "a cake" they mean an instance of the category.  Instances are countable, categories not.  If I say "Today we're going to discuss Tragedy", it would not do to ask "Which one?" but if I said "Today we're going to discuss tragedies" one could reasonably ask "Which ones?"

I want cake can be paraphrased as I want some cake or, given how it is conventionally served and consumed, I want a piece [or a slice or a serving] of cake, and each of those noun-phrase objects of the verb want is singular, taking the article a.
